# paramiko - How to connect a remote server from sudoer instance

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

1 - Verified whether paramiko code able to connect to instance with sudo access 
2 - After above succesful run, I tried to execute this command -

`ssh_client.exec_command(command)`

command = `sudo su - abc -c 'sftp -o <path to ssh key> -o Port=22 <username@server.com>'`

Question - Do not see any output script gets stuck.

I have also looked into doc - [pysftp doc](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/cookbook.html) and [paramiko doc](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/channel.html)

Any suggestion appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the two solutions:

```
command = "sudo -S - abc -c 'sftp -o <path to ssh key> -o Port=22 <username@server.com>"
```

Or

```
command = 'rsync -avz --rsh="sshpass -p password ssh -l username -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" server.com:remote_path local_path'
```